# how to cp a cd/dvd as an image file?

Tags: dvd, cd

How can I copy the content of a cd or dvd as an image file (such as an iso file0, which can be mounted as a virtual cd or dvd? Prefer command line solutions, and also interested to know gui solution.

will the size of the image file be the same as the storage size of the cd or dvd, or just the total size of the files in the cd or dvd (which can save more space)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dd` for it.

An example:

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom of=/tmp/ImageName.iso
```

Comment: Thanks. will the size of the image file be the same as the storage size of the cd or dvd, or just the total size of the files in the cd or dvd (which is preferred because it can save  space)?

Comment: For `dd` the size of the partition matters, not what's in there. It will just make a byte-to-byte copy of whatever partition you provide the command with.